# Google Chrome - where to get all the regedit policy flags?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, policy

In some Banks, Government Google Chrome is hammered with there local policy as a result often when we go on-site our stable applications does not work anymore.

Because of there is no well documentation available about this local regedit changes, people waste months fixing a tiny issues in Banks, Government zone.

Can anyone please list the whole mystery of regedit values which makes Google Chrome modifications such as i have seen someone puts webcam disabled, microphone disabled, touch screen disabled, etc etc (there is a huge settings but no-body documented them, can we have them all dumped here?).

Comment: which Windows version(s) is this for?

Comment: They use Windows 7 or windows 8.1 pro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking for but to answer your title here's a list of all the policys

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3

Chromium shares the same policys as Google Chrome but beware that some policys might not yet be implemented

EDIT: Made a RAW copy on request. [Chrome policy list](https://docs.google.com/document/d/142FS24RddepKTkWV8VepV59wpmIHOyFi-dEVd4tIMs4/pub)

Comment: YES - this is the correct answer. Before they remove the website can you please list them in this answer as permanent? so that even google remove those web site reference it stays in our asset as SO?

Comment: How do I add it as permanent ? Or do you mean just raw copy paste ?

Comment: YES - RAW copy paste using Google Documents where you can paste web sites as document. Often i have noticed Google team without warning or notice change on the fly there documentation as a result people reading this answer will fail after few months/years. So maybe it would be nice if you make the existing copy paste page in a some web page which stays forever unchanged for Chrome 44. Thank you!!!

Comment: Edited it to the answer. I hope it is what you were asking for

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "chrome://flags" (without quotes) inside chrome's URL bar, this will show you a load of Flags that may be helpful, not entirely sure if it will hold exactly what you're looking for, but you never know.

Comment: Some enterprise (governemnt) does not even allow you accessing chrome://flags there admin block those even via regedit. so we need raw regedit answer.